# Analysing stack frame of C program in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'd like to ask if there is any option to gcc for Linux which allows debugging stack frames of given procedure of program written in C?

I know I can compile my program with -ggdb3 gcc parameter and it allows me to find out what are the symbols in this program. But is there any method to find out how the procedures arguments are passed (via stack or registers)?

I've got program which overwrites stack causing SEGV and I'd like to analyse it from the same program. First I'd like to find the problematic procedure and then I'm planning to find the place of the error.

Comment: lookup pawngdb gdb extension.

Comment: gdb can certainly help you find out where the SEGV is coming from.  you can use the backtrace commands to see what is on the stack and then switch to the last frame that has your code it in and see what caused the error.  see http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.  One I prefer is to look at the actual generated code as it tells me exactly what is being executed.  You can get this when compiling with gcc or g++.  This will create a file with a `.S` suffix.

For example, `gcc -S helloworld.c` will also create a file called `helloworld.S` which contains the assembly code.

If you don't have source you can use tools like objdump to turn the binary code into a disassembly.

Lots of examples if you search for `gcc assembly output`